# Passing python data types as function arguments

Tags: functions, function-construction, import, python, arguments

I've a few python data types

```py
edges = [(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,5), (2,6), (5,6), (3,4), (3,7), (6,7), (7,8), (2,9)];
vl = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
ew = {(1, 2) : 49.6, (1,3): 74.4, (1, 4) : 49.6, (2,5): 37.2, (2, 6) : 74.4, (5, 6): 49.6, (3, 4) : 37.2, (3, 7):24.8, (6, 7) : 62, (7, 8) : 37.2, (2, 9) : 24.8}
vd = {1:[75., 25., 0], 2:[115., 45., 0], 3:[10., 5., 0], 4:[45., 0, 0], 5:[90., 60., 0], 6:[45., 55., 0], 7:[0, 25., 0], 8:[10., 50.,0], 9:[115.,  25.,0]};
```

I want to pass these variables to a function that will convert these to Mathematica expression. I want to do something like below,

```
solutiond[edges_, vd_, vl_, ew_] := (
  {edges, vl, ew, vd} = 
    ImportString[#, "PythonExpression"]& /@ {"edges","vl","ew","vd"};)

solutiond[edges, vd, vl, ew]
```

But I am not sure how to pass these input arguments here

```
{"edges", "vl", "ew", "vd"}
```

In python I use `.format`.

Suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call `ImportString[..., "PythonExpression"]` Mathematica run it as an isolated environment:

```
ImportString["a=2", "PythonExpression"]

ImportString["a", "PythonExpression"] (* ERROR *)
```

The above code will raise an error because there is no defined name as `a`.

### Solution 1

what you could do is to start a `ExternalSession`, run your code in python then ask python to return each variable value:

```
session = StartExternalSession["Python"];

ExternalEvaluate[session, 
  "edges = [(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,5), (2,6), (5,6), (3,4), (3,7), (6,7), (7,8), (2,9)];
vl = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
ew = {(1, 2) : 49.6, (1,3): 74.4, (1, 4) : 49.6, (2,5): 37.2, (2, 6) : 74.4, (5, 6): 49.6, (3, 4) : 37.2, (3, 7):24.8, (6, 7) : 62, (7, 8) : 37.2, (2, 9) : 24.8}
vd = {1:[75., 25., 0], 2:[115., 45., 0], 3:[10., 5., 0], 4:[45., 0, 0], 5:[90., 60., 0], 6:[45., 55., 0], 7:[0, 25., 0], 8:[10., 50.,0], 9:[115.,  25.,0]};"];

ExternalEvaluate[session, #] & /@ {"edges", "vl", "ew", "vd"}

DeleteObject[session];
```

Output:

```
{{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {5, 6}, {3, 4}, {3, 7}, {6, 
   7}, {7, 8}, {2, 9}}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
  9}, <|{1, 2} -> 49.6, {1, 3} -> 74.4, {1, 4} -> 49.6, {2, 5} -> 
   37.2, {2, 6} -> 74.4, {5, 6} -> 49.6, {3, 4} -> 37.2, {3, 7} -> 
   24.8, {6, 7} -> 62, {7, 8} -> 37.2, {2, 9} -> 
   24.8|>, <|1 -> {75., 25., 0}, 2 -> {115., 45., 0}, 
  3 -> {10., 5., 0}, 4 -> {45., 0, 0}, 5 -> {90., 60., 0}, 
  6 -> {45., 55., 0}, 7 -> {0, 25., 0}, 8 -> {10., 50., 0}, 
  9 -> {115., 25., 0}|>}
```

### Solution 2

You could still use `ImportString` to import directly but your python code needs to be changed:

```
ImportString["[(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,5), (2,6), (5,6), (3,4), (3,7), (6,7), (7,8), (2,9)]", "PythonExpression"]
```

Out:

```
{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {5, 6}, {3, 4}, {3, 7}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {2, 9}}
```